# Registering a new Command Line Option in RYU App

Tags: openflow, ryu

I need to be able to read in a path file from my simple_switch.py application.I have added the following code to my simple_switch.py in python.

```
      LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 CONF = cfg.CONF
 CONF.register_cli_opts([
             cfg.StrOpt('path-file', default='test.txt',
                                              help='path-file')
     ])
```

I attempt to start the application as follows.

```
  bin/ryu-manager --observe-links --path-file test.txt ryu/app/simple_switch.py
```

However I get the following error.

```
usage: ryu-manager [-h] [--app-lists APP_LISTS] [--ca-certs CA_CERTS]
                   [--config-dir DIR] [--config-file PATH]
                   [--ctl-cert CTL_CERT] [--ctl-privkey CTL_PRIVKEY]
                   [--default-log-level DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL] [--explicit-drop]
                   [--install-lldp-flow] [--log-config-file LOG_CONFIG_FILE]
                   [--log-dir LOG_DIR] [--log-file LOG_FILE]
                   [--log-file-mode LOG_FILE_MODE]
                   [--neutron-admin-auth-url NEUTRON_ADMIN_AUTH_URL]
                   [--neutron-admin-password NEUTRON_ADMIN_PASSWORD]
                   [--neutron-admin-tenant-name NEUTRON_ADMIN_TENANT_NAME]
                   [--neutron-admin-username NEUTRON_ADMIN_USERNAME]
                   [--neutron-auth-strategy NEUTRON_AUTH_STRATEGY]
                   [--neutron-controller-addr NEUTRON_CONTROLLER_ADDR]
                   [--neutron-url NEUTRON_URL]
                   [--neutron-url-timeout NEUTRON_URL_TIMEOUT]
                   [--noexplicit-drop] [--noinstall-lldp-flow]
                   [--noobserve-links] [--nouse-stderr] [--nouse-syslog]
                   [--noverbose] [--observe-links]
                   [--ofp-listen-host OFP_LISTEN_HOST]
                   [--ofp-ssl-listen-port OFP_SSL_LISTEN_PORT]
                   [--ofp-tcp-listen-port OFP_TCP_LISTEN_PORT] [--use-stderr]
                   [--use-syslog] [--verbose] [--version]
                   [--wsapi-host WSAPI_HOST] [--wsapi-port WSAPI_PORT]
                   [--test-switch-dir TEST-SWITCH_DIR]
                   [--test-switch-target TEST-SWITCH_TARGET]
                   [--test-switch-tester TEST-SWITCH_TESTER]
                   [app [app ...]]
ryu-manager: error: unrecognized arguments: --path-file
```

It does look like I need to register a new command line option somewhere before I can use it.Can some-one point out to me how to do that? Also can someone explain how to access the file(text.txt) inside the program?

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track, however the CONF entry that you are creating actually needs to be loaded *before* your app is loaded, otherwise ryu-manager has no way of knowing it exists!

The file you are looking for is **flags.py**, under the ryu directory of the source tree (or under the root installation directory).

This is how the ryu/tests/switch/tester.py Ryu app defines it's own arguments, so you might use that as your reference:

```
CONF.register_cli_opts([
    # tests/switch/tester
    cfg.StrOpt('target', default='0000000000000001', help='target sw dp-id'),
    cfg.StrOpt('tester', default='0000000000000002', help='tester sw dp-id'),
    cfg.StrOpt('dir', default='ryu/tests/switch/of13',
               help='test files directory')
], group='test-switch')
```

Following this format, the CONF.register_cli_opts takes an array of config types exactly as you have done it (see **ryu/cfg.py** for the different types available).

You'll notice that when you run the ryu-manager help, i.e.

```
ryu-manager --help
```

the list that comes up is sorted by application (e.g. the group of arguments under 'test-switch options'). For that reason, you will want to specify a group name for your set of commands.

Now let us say that you used the group name 'my-app' and have an argument named 'path-file' in that group, the command line argument will be --my-app-path-file (this can get a little long), while you can access it in your application like this:

```
from ryu import cfg
CONF = cfg.CONF
path_file = CONF['my-app']['path_file']
```

Note the use of dash versus the use of underscores.

Cheers!